# attach load event to an image within iframe using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

There are a lot of pages about triggering on the loading of an iframe itself, but what I'd like to do is to trigger an event on the loading of an image within an iframe. I'll be doing this across multiple iframes and the image may have the same id in all of them. So whilst I can usually do:

```js
$("#image_loading").load(function(){
  alert("loaded");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image_loading" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Example.svg/1024px-Example.svg.png">
```

and I can identify images within an iframe using find like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gL1c3a1/2/) (as I can't make iframes work in SO) using:

```
$("#IFRAME_ID").contents().find('img')[0].id;
```

epascarello has pointed out that these can be combined with:

```
$("#IFRAME_ID").contents().find('img').on("load", function() {})
```

Which does work sometimes. However, the images being loaded have an inconsistent load time, and so when I try the following:

```
doc.open();
doc.write(<img src="IMAGE URL HERE"/>);
doc.close();
$("#trial"+index).contents().find('img').on("load",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

I only inconsistently get the "hi" alert when an image is loaded. I assume because the image has already loaded by the on load event.

Is there a way to reliably get trigger an event when the image in the iframe is loaded?

Comment: So `$("#IFRAME_ID").contents().find('img').on("load", function() {})` does not work? Also are you sure the image is not already loaded before you add the listener?

Comment: ah!- I tried $("#IFRAME_ID").contents().find('img')[0].on("load", function(0 {} ) (note the 0) which didn't work. This kind of works, but doesn't reliably capture the image load (i.e. sometimes does, sometimes doesn't). I'm wondering if this is due to the image already having loaded by the time the line you wrote is executed on some occasions, and not on others. The images I'm downloading are from dropbox generally, so have inconsistent download times - so I think your second comment applies to that problem.

Comment: i'll adjust the question to reflect the inconsistency problem

Comment: actually I can't replicate the inconsistency problem - doesn't emerge in the following https://jsfiddle.net/4gL1c3a1/8/

Comment: Why are you not just adding the onload handler on the element from the start?

Comment: doc.write(<img src="IMAGE URL HERE" onload="parent.yourFuntion(this)"/>);

Comment: you mean within the script that's wrapped in the iframe? This script is dynamic, and i won't be controlling what's in it - what I'm writing is a tool to handle other people's scripts which will go in the iframe